# how to make sequelize full join?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Do you know how to make a **full join** with sequelize and postgresql? I know that if you put required: false you can make a **inner join** and without required you make a **left outer join** but I need a **full join** to show all my tables this is my query:

```
models.assessment.findAll({
    attributes: [
      'asmt_users.sso',
      'asmt_users->users.first_name',
      'asmt_users->users.last_name',
      'assessment.assessment_id',
      'applications.app_name',
      'statuses.status',
      'services.service'
    ],
    include: [{model: models.application},
      {model: models.service},
      {model: models.status},
      {model: models.asmt_user, include: [{model: models.user}]
    }]
  });
```

thank you!

Comment: So you are trying to write a query to pull down everything from every single one of those tables, regardless of any joins? I'd be interested in your reasoning. Can you post the SQL you want to achieve?

Comment: Well the problem here is not all the information of all the tables maybe only the join with asmt_user and assessment is the problem, I made an Query that give's me what I want to let me show you in another comment:

In fact I cannot make the right join, this query works with the right join or full join in the users and assessment join well but sequelize only give me inner join and left join

Comment: SELECT users.sso, users.first_name, users.last_name,assessments.assessment_id,applications.app_name,services.service,statuses.status,assessments.assessment_type
FROM report_manager.assessment_user
left join report_manager.users
on (users.sso = assessment_user.sso)
full join report_manager.assessments
on assessments.id = assessment_user.assessment_id
left join applications
on applications.id = assessments.id
left join report_manager.services
on services.id = assessments.service_id
left join statuses
on statuses.id = assessments.status_id;

Comment: I founded my problem is the relationships in the sequelize models, I was not calling it correctly sorry for the problem!